# Mapbox Android SymbolLayer Reset Filter

Tags: java, android, filter, mapbox, layer

I have SymbolLayer in style. I can filter SymbolLayer with setFilter() method. However I cannot find reset filter method about SymbolLayer. Filtering code is at below. How can I reset SymbolLayer filter?

I've tried filtering with none value but it is not working.

```java
String category = "Tennis";
SymbolLayer pointLayer = (SymbolLayer) style.getLayer(layerID);
pointLayer.setFilter(eq(get("Branch"), literal(category)));
```

This code is filtering code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me so far:

```
 pointLayer.setFilter(neq(literal(""), ""));
```

A layer can only have a single filter at a time, you just add a filter that is always true to overwrite your filter.

Don't ask me what *literal* does, I can't get it to always be true, so I used the *neq*(not equals) to get my hack working.

I could not find any documentation, that is up to date for Android, on how to do this the right way :(